# Database Structure: Creating Person table to be referenced by other tables

Tags: database, foreign-keys

I have a question about entity creations that is specific to a student information system that i am building. i have created a Person table (id..) and i am trying to find out how i can handle my student, parent references. is it a good idea to create two separate tables (Student, Parent) that reference the Person table by FK relationship? All of the details about a Person (firstname, last name, SSN ...) have been set in the Person table but there are differences between a parent and student, how do you handle this in a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are fundamental differences between parents and students, two tables would be the preferred solution. This way you can easily create a relation connecting the students and parents.

The other option is to use null values in the columns that do not apply for a given record. However, it will be more difficult to ensure that the relation always connects a student and parent.

Comment: If i create two seperate tables (Parent, Student), then i have in total three tables (including Person table). How do i avoid creating duplicate records in each one of these tables. My application needs to create a Student and connect them to a Parent but i should have clarified about my question. I was asking do i even need the Person table?

Comment: The person table is not needed. Technically parent and student can be sub-classes of person. But that is a lot of extra work for little benefit in this example. I would definitely migrate the entries from the person table to the correct (student or parent) table and drop the person table.

Comment: I used the Person table due to the number of increasing roles in my application. I did however end up creating the (student & parent) table for easy relation and connection as you mentioned. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Casey Robinson in that its a clean solution.

But if you already have a populated Person table which is being used by other code... in short you can't change the Person table then here is what I would suggest:

Create a table (studentParent) which will have two columns (student_id and parent_id) both foreign keys. The studentParent.student_id = Person.id of the student and studentParent.parent_id = Person.id of the parent.

This way you won't have to change the Person table. And will be able to create the parent, student relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details it seems that two tables Person and Student should be sufficient. Have two columns in Student table like Student_id and Parent_id each of which is a FK to person_id in Person table. This is assuming you will need to know for only student which is a parent and not for every person. Also assuming that both student and parent are person.